# Limit ngFor iterations to a fixed number

Tags: angular, carousel, ngfor

i have a page with a carousel, and i want a max of 7 dots, even i have 10 slides.
I searching but i dont discover nothing yet.
this is my code

```
<div class="subject-pagination">
  <div class="page-item" *ngFor="let subject of pageIdentityTraitArray.subjects"
    [ngStyle]="subject.nid === subjectId ? {'background-color': pageIdentityTraitArray.color} :'' ">
    <a [routerLink]="[ '/code-of-ethics/identity-trait', pageId, subject.nid, '1' ]"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can i limit to 7 dots, please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an index to your ngFor statement and use this in a conditional to only add links to a maximum of 7:

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let page of pages; let i = index">
        <li *ngIf="i < 7">
            <a [href]="page.link">{{page.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you could use the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) to truncate your array at 7 elements:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let page of pages | slice:0:7">
        <a [href]="page.link">{{page.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Both methods shown on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmjmqa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html

It's possible (if unlikely as Leonardo points out) SlicePipe will need to be imported:

```
import { SlicePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

E.g. applying slice to your original code:

```
<div class="subject-pagination">
    <div class="page-item" *ngFor="let subject of pageIdentityTraitArray.subjects | slice:0:7"
[ngStyle]="subject.nid === subjectId ? {'background-color': pageIdentityTraitArray.color} :'' ">
        <a [routerLink]="[ '/code-of-ethics/identity-trait', pageId, subject.nid, '1' ]"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to import the SlicePipe if you already have imported the `CommonModule` or `BrowserModule` in your module